# Problems with vue router in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I need some help.
I compile my vue app with npm run serve, and when I upload to the test server and travel to one of the routes and reload the page it returns 404 error

Comment: If you're using History mode for your router (routes without `#!` in the URL), your server needs to be setup to always respond with the `index.html` file in case of a 404. More info [in the docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)

Comment: Please clarify the problem, what have you tried, in what the other working routes different.